# How to better ask problems from known contests?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, contests

As we know, AoPS has got contest collections, containing threads where users discuss corresponding contest problems. Therefore, is it really necessary to ask them on mathematics stack exchange, if one can find answers on AoPS?

In my opinion, it is still necessary if one wants to ask for clarification of a certain solution, or wants to let people check if his solution is correct (or partial solution can be completed). But if he is simply looking for a solution to the problem, is it necessary to keep on discussing the problem?

Here, I mean the contest problems which has been collected and answered on AoPS.

Comment: In the event that math.stackexchange outlives AOPS it would be good to have solutions here as well as there.

Comment: Why, @Gerry?  This site has quality control; we are distinctly different from Brilliant.org, and from AOPS.  If AOPS disappears, that might be a good thing.  Why do you feel we (math.se) needs to contain every question ever asked on all other math sites???

Comment: For me, the main thing is to give the source of the problem.  Lots of problems resemble current contest questions, sometimes because people throw in the current year for contest preparation, some types of homework, some exams. Next, there are often errors in the problems; if we could see the pages of related material as well as the single problem, we could judge the intent.

Comment: for example, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627589/when-is-sum-s-aa-ba-c-ge0-true   you alluded to a "Phan Kim Hung"   theorem. Some of his(?)  books on inequalities can be downloaded. However, I could not find the relevant content in his books. Some other mathematician involved in contest prep might decide to call something by the name  of the person who came up with it, but we have no way to get specifics.

Comment: @amWhy, contest problems tend to be pretty interesting. If AOPS disappears, and with it the answers to those interesting problems, I don't see that as a good thing.

Comment: @Gerry AOPS is geared to children and highschoolers.  When problem statements are posted with (Can you help me solve this?  I'm totally stuck. Please give me the solution), they are not appropriate on this site, nor are answers to them, per "how to ask a good question" and "EOQS" each FAQs on meta.  If you find that level of contest problems interesting, feel free to spend time contributing at AoPS.

Comment: @amWhy, my experience is somewhat different. When I see an interesting question on mathstack that I think may be a duplicate, I type some key part of it into approach0. Often I find the question has been discussed on AOPS (and sometimes only on AOPS, and not on mathstack). I'm sure you're right about the general level of AOPS, but all I see there is what I'm searching for there, and what I'm searching for is interesting questions.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the right approach is. A little off-topic, but I'm not comfortable with people on AoPS asking interesting questions without showing any effort and receiving full answers. Wouldn't that give grade schoolers the impression, "Oh, I can just ask a hard math question and expect people to solve it for me" as if they are using Chegg or Yahoo Answers? If there's a question on MSE that shows effort, I think it's fine to leave a comment linking an AoPS post with the exact same question that has an answer since the way AoPS runs things isn't our business.

Comment: Agree with you, @Accelerator.

Comment: On "is it really necessary to ask on MSE if the answer is at AoPS", do you think an average MSE audience has anything to offer compared to AoPS folks? Why, for example, is the "clarification-type" question better asked on MSE than on AoPS? I would put it this way : if you want an MSE-treatment of your question, which is a good question-answer pair ,then ask on MSE (in the right way, goes without saying). If you wish to "discuss" your question or , I would argue, even want to clarify large parts of an attempt you've written, I would vote to close it here. AoPS is a better place for that.

Comment: On "how to ask" : in addition to the quality standards, for a contest question one should provide evidence that the contest is not ongoing, by explicitly stating a source and ensuring that this source is as accessible as possible via a link to it or a proper citation.

Answer (score 3):

Users do not necessarily search on AoPS to see if a solution to their problem has been posted there. In my opinion, it should be fine **as long as it meets our site's quality standards**. It may even be beneficial as pointed out by Gerry Myerson in the comments.

Of course, you are free to link to an AoPS page and see if that helps the OP, but I don't think we should disregard a question if it has been answered on *another* website.

Comment: Meeting quality standards is the key point here, and a point @GerryMyerson seems neglect.

Comment: @amW, the question is whether we should answer at m.se questions that have already been answered at AoPS. I've said, why not? I haven't mentioned quality standards, because I take it as given that we only answer questions at m.se if they meet m.se quality standards.

Comment: @Gerry And the title of the post: "How to better ask problems from known contests?", is what I am addressing.  How to successfully ask a good question on this site? You jumped in to say:  "I like contest questions", and all your comments up to the one immediately above, failed to address that point.

Comment: For youthdoo: [How to ask a good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C130.2984) answers your question, and what @bobeyt6 refers to in boldface.